# Only projects with 'pom' packaging can declare modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to add some modules to a java maven project but I get the following error message

```
"Only projects with 'pom' packaging can declare modules"
```

How can I switch my current project to declare a 'pom' packaging?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `<packaging>pom</packaging>` in the project section:

```
<project ...>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Packaging.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a noob question but I'm new to maven.